# sort and reduce array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

i have an array of objects like this :

```js
const array = [ { type: "sale", product: "aaa" } , { type: "rent", product: "bbb" } , { type: "sale", product: "ccc" }];
```

and i use this function to summarize the array

```js
array.reduce((acc, o) => ((acc[o.type] = (acc[o.type] || 0) + 1), acc),{})
```

result :

```js
{sale: 2, rent: 1}
```

but i wanna sort this summary object **Ascending** like this **{rent: 1,sale: 2}**
Do I need to use another function  ?
Or modify the current function and how  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript objects are *typically* considered to be an **unordered** collection of key/value pairs (yes, there are caveats, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) for details). If you want an ordered result, you *should* use an array instead.

That being said, for objects with string keys, the keys are ordered in insertion order, so it's sufficient to convert your object to an array, sort that as desired, and convert it back to an object again.

```js
const array = [
  { type: "sale", product: "aaa" } ,
  { type: "rent", product: "bbb" } ,
  { type: "sale", product: "ccc" }
];

const raw = array.reduce((a, v) => (a[v.type] = (a[v.type] || 0) + 1, a), {});
const sorted = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(raw).sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v1 - v2)
);

console.log(sorted);
```